# Erro na query de seleção sobre solicitações em rede social

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, select

Olá, no meu projeto eu preciso listar as pessoas e as solicitações recebidas pelo usuário, porém na hora de listar as pessoas, preciso listar apenas aquelas que não enviaram ou que o usuário não enviou solicitações, no caso, minha tabela de amizade guarda status da solicitação, sendo 0 para pendente

```
SELECT * FROM tbUsuario user JOIN tbAmizade am, tbGenMus gen WHERE NOT
((am.fkUsuarioSend = user.usId AND am.fkUsuarioReceive = {$_SESSION['usuario']['usId']})
OR (am.fkUsuarioSend = {$_SESSION['usuario']['usId']} AND am.fkUsuarioReceive = user.UsId))
AND NOT user.usId = {$_SESSION['usuario']['usId']} AND gen.idGenMus = user.fkGenMus;
```

criei essa query e funcionou por um momento, mas quando o usuário enviava mais de uma solicitação, a query começou a duplicar os resultados e colocar os que não deviam aparecer.

Comment: Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página Como perguntar para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema possa ser no seu JOIN, você pode tentar utilizar o ON para especificar a condição do JOIN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbUsuario user 
     JOIN tbAmizade am ON user.id = am.user_id, 
     tbGenMus gen 
[...]
```

Sem utilizar o ON, o seu JOIN vai ser equivalente a um CROSS JOIN, resultando no produto cartesiano da ligação entre as duas tabelas.